# Detect if Firebase has read from the database in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm playing around with Firebase and Android and I'm storing my data online in Firebase. I have an activity with 3 EditTexts and a button and I want it to essentially check that the 3 values in the textboxes are in the database and if so, move onto the next activity.

These values are static and so I'm using the .addListenerForSingleValueEvent method and using it as an anonymous function. I want this to work even if the device is offline but if any of the values come back as null then I want it to reject moving to the next activity.

Is there any way to detect when Firebase has either retrieved a value from the database or retrieved null from the database? This way I could check each value consecutively and if any return null then reject changing activities.

The only other thing I could think to do is to nest the anonymous functions for each listener but that sounds like it would be a bad idea.

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of describing the code and the problem, edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will drastically improve the chances of getting an actionable answer.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry about that I'll try work on something now

Comment: It sounds like you would want to have these three fields stored under the same node. Then with a single call of addListenerForSingleValueEvent, you can retrieve a mapping that includes the three fields and then do your comparisons client side. If you include code, I'd be happy to show you how to do it gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i understand you want to check for values in your database before moving to the next activity. My advice is that

1) create an ArrayList of DatabaseReference that point to the data locations in firebase in your activity.

```
Arraylist<DatabaseReference> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("my_child_node_1"):
list.add(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("my_child_node_2"):
list.add(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("my_child_node_3"):
```

2) create an interface and a call back method.

```
public static interface DataCallback {
    static void onDataAdded(String string); //Use the necessary data type
}
```

3) use the interface to create a constructor for your Event listener.

```
public static class DataListener implements ValueEventListener {

    private DataCallback dataCallback;

    public DataListener(DataCallback dataCallback) {
        this.dataCallback = dataCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String data = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

        //This is step 4
        if(dataCallback!=null) {
            dataCallback.onContactAdded(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
}
```

4) Pass the value from the listener to your activity as follows inside onDataChange() method of the Listener

```
    if(dataCallback!=null) {
        dataCallback.onContactAdded(data);
    }
```

5) implement the interface in your activity and override its callback method

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DataCallback{

private EditText edittext1;
private EditText edittext2;
private EditText edittext3;
private ArrayList<String> my_list;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //do stuff...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataAdded(String data) {

    }
}
```

6) Instantiate and add the listener in your activity's onResume() method

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    DataListener listener = new DataListener(this);
    list[0].addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
    list[1].addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
    list[2].addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
}
```

7) get the values from firebase in your activity inside the Callback method as follows

```
@Override
public void onDataAdded(String data){
my_list.add(data);
}
```

8) you can check if the values gotten from firebase match the values gotten from the EditText inside the OnClicklistener for you button.

```
if (button != null) {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(my_list.contains(edittext1.getText().toString)){
                    if(my_list.contains(edittext.getText().toString)){
                        if(my_list.contains(edittext.getText().toString)){
                        startActivity(new intent(MyActivity.this, NextActivity.class))
                        }
                    } 
                }   
            }
        });
    }
```

9) remove the listeners inside the onPause() method.

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    list[0].removeEventListener(listener);
    list[1].removeEventListener(listener);
    list[2].removeEventListener(listener);
}
```